# Change the Anaconda Navigator default file location

Tags: python, anaconda

i am just started with python and just installed Anaconda on windows 10. I changed the install directory to "C:\Anaconda3". Everytime I start Anaconda Navigator it creates settings files/folders (.conda, .anaconda, and .condarc) in my ...\user\ directory. How can I change the location for this files?

Comment: Hi , Welcome to stack overflow  .Please take the time to read to see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask,

Comment: I have spent the past 2 days reading solutions. I tried editing the starting folder in short cuts and editing jupyter_notebook_config.py. Neither work.

Comment: Actually  having trouble understanding your question, can you reproduce your question

Comment: Sure. Anaconda created a Python scripts folder, and log.setting files (.conda, etc) in my \user\ folder (which I think it uses as its default/root folder). But I use Google sync in a different folder and want all of those there (...\user\Document\Gsync\)